# Inline recursive functions

Tags: c, recursion, inline

I thought that calling a `inline` function inside of itself wouldn't be allowed because it would lead to something like infinite source code when the function's invokations get replaced with its body(if that happends). But, when I test is that allowed, I get a `Segmentation fault`. Example code:

```c
static inline void a(void){
    a();
}
int main(void){
    a();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to ask why is not a compile-error generated in the first place, and also why this leads to a `Segmentation fault`. Thanks for reaching out.

Comment: `inline` doesn't force inlining, it's only a hint in this regard. It doesn't add extra restrictions on function body; if it's not inlineable (or the compiler doesn't feel like inlining it), the hint is silently ignored. Your segfault isn't related to inlining.

Comment: does you code crashes with noinline?

Comment: I acknowledged that, @HolyBlackCat. I wrote "(if that happends)".

Comment: No @leo, it doesn't.

Comment: what compiler are you using? Have you checked the disassembled code?

Comment: your code crashes because of stack overflow :-/ It is not inline-related issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @HolyBlackCat mentioned - inline is only a hint for a compiler. Compiler ignores it in a lot of cases.

As for your test - your recursive code causes a crash because of **stack overflow error** - every function call reserves a memory block on the stack and your program runs out of memory.

Comment: I was surprised that it would compile, so I didn't check wheter the same thing happends when the function isn't inline. Also, would a compilation error occur if the compiler wouldn't have ignored the `inline` keyword?

Comment: Speaking for msvc & gcc they would just ignore the directive. I've never seen compilation errors because of improper `inline`

Comment: Somebody said that it would lead to infinite compile time.

Comment: @markoj Then ask this _somebody_ for a working example. Unless that is provided, I doubt this claim.